# make jquery execute upon submit

Tags: jquery, input, submit, calculator

How can I execute this script with submit button?

http://jsfiddle.net/eN7S6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
$(".calc").change(function(){       
    var inputone = $('#inputone').val();
    var inputtwo = $('#inputtwo').val();
    var totalTotal = ((inputone * 1) * (inputtwo * 1));     
    $('#Total').text(totalTotal);

}); 

   $('#update').click(function() { 
    showTab($('#Total').val());
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, or at least you shouldn't!
Once a submit button is clicked, a form is generally submitted, but as you have no form, all you need is a regular button and an event handler that triggers the change event :

```
$('#update').click(function() { 
    $('.calc').trigger('change');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eN7S6/1/)

Comment: This doesn't do the job...All I need is the result to be updated upon pressing button, in this case updating field and clicking literally anywhere will make the result update automatically...

Comment: So just remove the change handler, and stick the code in the click handler, like [**THIS**](http://jsfiddle.net/eN7S6/2/)